# Documenting CPU for running process

Tags: powershell, cpu

Ref. http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2013/04/16/documenting-cpu-load-for-running-processes.aspx

This PowerShell code runs great locally, but when changing it to remote computer, it does not work..  I would also think it be helpful to add not only CPU Usage, but memory as well.

```
$CPUPercent = @{
  Name = 'CPUPercent'
  Expression = {
    $TotalSec = (New-TimeSpan -Start $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds
    [Math]::Round( ($_.CPU * 100 / $TotalSec), 2)
  }
}


Get-Process -computername RemoteServer | 
 Select-Object -Property Name, CPU, $CPUPercent, Description |
 Sort-Object -Property CPUPercent -Descending |
 Select-Object -First 4
```

And, shows for the results:

> Name                                        CPU
>   CPUPercent                                  Description
>
> ----                                        ---                                         ----------                                  -----------                                svchost
>   sysedge
>   svchost
>   svchost

Changing it back to local run, we see:

> Name
>   CPU                                  CPUPercent Description
>
> ----                                                                                ---                                  ---------- -----------
>   powershell_ise                                                         5.578125                                        0.51 Windows PowerShell ISE
>   Application                              2634.765625                                        0.24 Some Agent Executable
>   svchost                                1926.96875                                        0.18 Generic Host Process for Win32 Services
>   mcshield                                 1903.875                                        0.17 McAfee On-Access Scanner service